# why is the lock keyword not working with this multi-threading implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm trying to use a Parallel.ForEach() construct for multi-threading and I'm encountering some issues. Specifically, some of the data needs to be evaluated differently, which appeared to create some issues within the ForEach() construct where some properties were getting set with values from different threads.  I thought that I would be able to simply wrap that particular code with a lock but the issue still occurs.  Can you identify what the issue might be by reviewing the following code?:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/IDUGbP

Here's the inline code:

```
using SecurityApi.Core.Models;
using SecurityApi.Core.Repositories;
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoMapper;
using SecurityApi.EntityFramework;
using System.DirectoryServices;

namespace SecurityApi.Repositories
{
    [Export(typeof(IADUserRepository))]
    public class ADUserRepository : IADUserRepository
    {
        private Object etlLock = new Object();

        public async Task<List<Core.Models.ADUser>> GetADUsersFromAD(string domainName)
        {
            var domainId = await new DomainRepository().GetDomainId(domainName);
            var adUsers = new ConcurrentBag<Core.Models.ADUser>();
            var adGroups = new ConcurrentBag<Core.Models.ADGroup>();

            return await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName))
                {
                    // init vars
                    var up = new UserPrincipal(context);
                    var ps = new PrincipalSearcher(up);
                    Core.Models.ADUser adUser;

                    Parallel.ForEach(
                        ps.FindAll().ToList(), 
                        new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount }, 
                        result =>
                    {
                        if (!result.DistinguishedName.Contains("OU=Users")) return;

                        //set ad user properties
                        var userPrincipal = result as UserPrincipal;
                        adUser.Name = userPrincipal.Name;
                        adUser.FirstName = userPrincipal.GivenName;
                        adUser.LastName = userPrincipal.Surname;

                        lock (etlLock)
                        {
                            //get a directory entry representation for accessing special properties
                            var directoryEntry = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;

                            //user principal name
                            adUser.UserPrincipalName = directoryEntry.Properties["UserPrincipalName"].Value?.ToString();

                            //employee id
                            adUser.EmployeeId = directoryEntry.Properties["EmployeeId"].Value?.ToString();
                        }

                        #endregion

                        adUsers.Add(adUser);
                    });
                }

                return adUsersList;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Extract the minimal reproducable relevant part of your code and copy it here.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I reduced the code a bit at the url above but most of the code is still needed

Comment: @user9393635 please put the code in your SO post. It should not be linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the temporary `adUser` variable is defined in an outer scope from the `Parallel.ForEach` block, which results in different threads modifying it. Instead, consider just moving that definition to the body of the foreach, where you actually set the variables. That way each thread will get it's own variable. Of course the question here is whether there are duplicate references which Parallel.Foreach operates on, but I assume there aren't.

Here how I'd modify your code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gFb5z6